# Working through a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops, nested-lists

I'm pretty new to Python and am trying to work through a list of lists.

Say I have:

```
myList = [[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13],[29,28,27,26]]
```

and a function called     myFunction

I could write:

```
for x in myList:
   for y in x:
     myFunction(y)
```

However, that would just call myFunction on each individual item in all the sublists. How would I incorporate something that I could also call when I finish up all the items in each sublist (e.g. I would call 1, 2, 3 and 4, and then the loop would realize it is at the end of the sublist and I could call that sublist).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Do what you want in outer loop:

```
>>> for x in myList:
...     for y in x:
...         print(y)
...     print(x) # <---
...
1
2
3
4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
10
11
12
13
[10, 11, 12, 13]
29
28
27
26
[29, 28, 27, 26]
```

Comment: Thanks! What if what I would want to do in the outer loop can only be done once the item in the inner loop has been completed? In this case, I would want to work on the items in the inner loop for each sublist, then call the sublist, then move on to the items in the next sublist.

Comment: @John, In the above code, `print(x)` is only executed only after the inner loop has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

[John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2718796/john), it is indented syntax of `Python`,
while it is indented it is a *block* of code, i.e. all commands are in pack (in block):

```
for x in myList:
    # block of code started
    for y in x:
        # here is new block
        # some here will be called totally "all elements in all sublists" times
        # i.e. "number of elements in x" times 
        # per "number of sublist in myList" times
        # and here will be called the same number of times (it is block)
    # here you're out of "for y in x" loop now (you're in previous block)
    # some here will be called "myList" number of times 
    # and here
# here you are out of "for x in myList" loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want:

```
def myFunction(y):
    print y

myList = [[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13],[29,28,27,26]]

for x in range(len(myList)):
   print "Sublist:",x, myList[x]
   for y in myList[x]:
     myFunction(y)
```